# Prevent default behavior of a link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would I prevent a link from automatically taking me to the next page? Essentially, I have a list of links, but first, I want to perform a check before the link is followed.

For example...

```
<tr ng-repeat= "match in matches">
    <td>
        <a href= {{match.link}} ng-click= "check_link(match.link)"> Click me </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I don't know is the javascript code inside "check_link" that will prevent the user from following the link if it fails the check.

Comment: No, not a dupe. This has to do with the correct way to use Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would create a directive in your application that easily allows you to prevent the default behaviour for links. This allows you to re-use this code any time that you want to prevent a link from behaving normally.

Example: When clicked, this link should just call the method sayHello(). It will not link to google.com

```
<a href="http://google.com" ng-click="sayHello()" stop-link>Say Hello</a>
```

Here is the code for the directive:

```
.directive('stopLink', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function($scope, ele, attrs) {
      ele.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Full working example available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/i5ZHDiwhnSVLkf59LxuU

This way, you can perform any necessary checks in sayHello(), and then use `$location` to redirect the user if you need to. You would likely want to use the `$location.path('/blah')` or `$location.url('http://google.com')` to change pages.

Full $location docs here: [https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/service/$location](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/service/%24location)

Comment: This is a good answer, but you should add in that you would need to inject `$location` into the controller/directive for completeness.

Comment: really dude, i mean, c'mon!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{{match.link}}" ng-click="check_link(match.link, $event)">Click me</a>
```

You have to pass the click event (available as $event) to your check_link function. Then, if you decide to prevent it from following, call preventDefault() on it.

```
$scope.check_link = function (yourParam, event) {
  // your code
  if (your_condition) event.preventDefault();
  // your code
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Angular function should take care of both the matching and the location redirection. Using a button tag instead of an anchor removes the automatic link following problem.

```
<tr ng-repeat= "match in matches">
    <td>
        <button type='button' ng-click= "check_link(match.link)"> Click me </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.check_link = function(whatToCheck){
    if(checksOut){
        $location.path(whatToCheck);
    }
};
```

If you want this to appear as a link, consider using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) and give it a class of 'btn btn-link'.